# Memory usage while variable usages

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular7

It is just to clear a doubt in my mind. It is not any framework based. But lets say am using Angular now.

Suppose if I have two variables a, and b. And am binding the same to my **HTML** using **Angular**.

Which is the best way to do it?

I mean,

```
this.data = {
    a: 10,
    b: "Name"
}
```

and bind it as

```
<span>{{data.a}} - {{data.b}}</span>
```

Or

```
this.a = 10;
this.b = "Name"
}
```

and bind it as

```
<span>{{a}} - {{b}}</span>
```

Which one is more efficient and Which use less memory?

Comment: If you want `efficiency` that's essentially speed *and* power - do you want speed or power?

Comment: I meant what is the best practice to follow.

Comment: If you need to move them around between functions, then the first one is the cleanest. If you need them just for use in the current context, the second one seems less verbose.

Comment: What will be in terms of browser memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much difference,but since the First method creates an object then two variables inside of it and the second way creates them directly in class, so the second method should be more efficient.